# MONGODB Aggregation Convert if field exists or do nothing

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query, type-conversion, aggregation

I need convert a field in MONGODB but if the field/path doesn't exist, I don't want it to be created.
I try using $$remove, $setfield, but without success in both.
Please, someone with knowledge on MongoDB, help me.

Note: check the images please. I tried to use $$remove instead of "null" but still nothing

```
[{
        "$addFields": {
            "fieldExists": {
                "$cond": [{
                        "$ifNull": ["$documentoAlterado.nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.total.ICMSTot.vBC", null]
                    }, true, false]
            }
        }
    }, {
        "$addFields": {
            "convertResult": {
                "$cond": [{
                        "$eq": ["$fieldExists", true]
                    }, {
                        "$convert": {
                            "input": "$documentoAlterado.nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.total.ICMSTot.vBC",
                            "to": "decimal",
                            "onError": "$documentoAlterado.nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.total.ICMSTot.vBC",
                            "onNull": "$documentoAlterado.nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.total.ICMSTot.vBC"
                        }
                    }, null]
            }
        }
    }, {
        "$addFields": {
            "documentoAlterado.nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.total.ICMSTot.vBC": "$convertResult"
        }
    }
]
```

[exists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyfO0.png)     [convert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9phU.png)       [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BwyC.png)   [replceRoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EacUN.png)

[ExistsMongoPlaygroud](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wKfXXGTesqo)
[NotExistsMongoPLayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NIrybeG2mRH)

Comment: Don't paste sample data as image. Instead, post as valid json documents.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$set` to conditionally update the `documentoAlterado` object with the `$convert` result.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "documentoAlterado.nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.total.ICMSTot.vBC": {
        "$convert": {
          "input": "$documentoAlterado.nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.total.ICMSTot.vBC",
          "to": "decimal",
          "onError": "$$REMOVE",
          "onNull": "$$REMOVE"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "documentoAlterado": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            $eq: [
              {},
              "$documentoAlterado.nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.total.ICMSTot"
            ]
          },
          "then": {
            // keep the other fields you want
            "cteProc": "$documentoAlterado.cteProc"
          },
          "else": "$documentoAlterado"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Dvzi15qctHE)

Comment: I tried using this "$replaceRoot" but the path was created anyway :/
I don't know hot to assign the value to the path/field IF it exists and do nothing IF DON'T (else)
Or maybe I'm doing it wrong, see in the last image, and thank you for your help.

Comment: @VitorDonadao As I said, don't post code and data as images. Post them as json documents. It is hard to comprehend now.

Comment: I post json documents on mongo playgrund and add the link. In the first case the path/field exists and I need to convert and replace the old value. In second one I don't have the path/field, but using the $addField this path was created with the last field null

Comment: I tried using this addFileds:
"$addFields": {
      "documentoAlterado.nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.total.ICMSTot.vBC": "$value",
      
    },

Comment: @VitorDonadao Your document structure is rather complicated. It could be simpler to conditionally choose the fields you need in `documentoAlterado` object like in the updated answer.